# Real transparent space in div. no text, just background visible

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with background, a text in it and another FIXED DIV which is placed on first DIV with background. I give a color to a FIXED DIV and text goes behind it, I don't give a color to DIV (want it transparent) and text is on it, I give transparency to DIV and both background and text is visible.

```
<div id="transparent"></div> <!-- fixed -->
<div id="content"> <!-- content with background and text -->
  content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
</div>
```

I want to achieve that there is main background, main text and a FIXED DIV that will show just background without any text (however I dont want to apply another background image on it that is cropped)

Here is what I want to achieve:
[image]

And here is jsFiddle to look how it is now: http://jsfiddle.net/9ggvD/

Comment: Pretty sure that can't be done. I might be wrong, but I don't think I am.

Comment: @Billy Moat i can ... see my trick in my answer :)

Comment: @D.A.V.O.O.D - I should rephrase my answer. I don't think it can be done without using a background image!

Comment: @Billy Moat yes, that's right, this is single solution for this question ! and without background-image cannot be done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See My Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/9ggvD/2/

i edited `#transparent` div css to :

```
#transparent
{
    position:fixed;
    background:url('http://c.dryicons.com/files/graphics_previews/blue.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    left:45px;
    top:300px;
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: so, you think this cannot be done without applying the same background to the fixed div that should be transparent, right? Before, I also figured out what you have done and I thought a better solution would exist. In case there is no such solution, I'll thankfully accept your answer. thanks.

Comment: @tmpmember no, this cannot be done without use a background, because text always become over on div if it is transparent

Comment: background-attachment: fixed; would have the same effect. A bit easier in my opinion

Comment: @colosso without background-image ? background-attachment for `#content` ?

Comment: no, you have to have background-image, just omit background-position and use background-attachment:fixed (in #transparent)

Comment: okay, i think it's enough, i'm accepting this solution, with its comment about background-attachment:fixed considered. THANKS A LOT D.A.V.O.O.D and colosso